# GitLab Errno::ENOSPC: No space left on device @ dir_s_mkdir

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-omnibus, gitlab-ce

After running a very long job my GitLab (on docker container) became unavailable, I believe it is full of tmp files or metadata, or something else. When I tried to do a backup I realized that the disk was full and I got the error below.

The way that I worked this around to keep working, was to double the disk size, now at least I can work.

I ran this command inside the container `gitlab-ctl registry-garbage-collect -m` (https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/raketasks/cleanup.html) and I could free up 3GB.

I thought it was an issue with Linux inodes, but as you can see below it wasn't. The official GitLab documentation sometimes is excellent but sometimes is going in circles.

I don't know what I supposed to delete to gain space, and overall I don't know what to do to avoid this issue next time, searched on Gitlab forums but somehow not clear tips or troubleshooting.

I'm affraid that if I ran that job one more time, I will collapse the disk again.

Any ideas on what to delete, what to add on `/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb` to avoid this, or how to implement some housekeeping or alerts for this purpose?, thank you.

```
docker exec -t gitlab gitlab-backup create
rake aborted!
Errno::ENOSPC: No space left on device @ dir_s_mkdir - /tmp/prometheus-mmap20201110-4631-1eio26e
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/config/initializers/7_prometheus_metrics.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/bundle:23:in `load'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => gitlab:backup:create => gitlab_environment => environment
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

```
[gitlab ~] df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs        7.8G   80K  7.8G   1% /dev
tmpfs           7.8G     0  7.8G   0% /dev/shm
/dev/nvme1n1p1   59G   56G  3.0G  96% /

[gitlab ~] df -iH
Filesystem     Inodes IUsed IFree IUse% Mounted on
devtmpfs         2.1M   516  2.1M    1% /dev
tmpfs            2.1M     1  2.1M    1% /dev/shm
/dev/nvme1n1p1   4.0M  160k  3.8M    5% /
```

**Gitlab version**

```
root@gitlab:/# gitlab-rake gitlab:env:info

System information
System:
Proxy:      no
Current User:   git
Using RVM:  no
Ruby Version:   2.6.6p146
Gem Version:    2.7.10
Bundler Version:1.17.3
Rake Version:   12.3.3
Redis Version:  5.0.9
Git Version:    2.28.0
Sidekiq Version:5.2.9
Go Version: unknown

GitLab information
Version:    13.4.4-ee
Revision:   4196ccb4738
Directory:  /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails
DB Adapter: PostgreSQL
DB Version: 11.9
URL:        https://
HTTP Clone URL: https://
SSH Clone URL:  git@
Elasticsearch:  no
Geo:        no
Using LDAP: no
Using Omniauth: yes
Omniauth Providers:

GitLab Shell
Version:    13.7.0
Repository storage paths:
- default:  /var/opt/gitlab/git-data/repositories
GitLab Shell path:      /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-shell
Git:        /opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/git
```

Comment: Do you have the GitLab installation, and the gitlab-runner, running on the same machine?

Comment: @Rekovni I have separate machines for runner and Gitlab. Should I look for something in the runner too?

Comment: Potentially yes; from the sounds of your question `After running a very long job my GitLab (on docker container) became unavailable`, it seems that the gitlab-runner machine is running out of disk space, not the GitLab server itself. I would check what's happening on there. Also you can use `ncdu` to view what is taking up space on your GitLab server itself